# Using local notifications for timed intervals in WatchKit and iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit

I'm creating a timer app that will fire off a sequence of Local Notifications that will relay from the iPhone app to the apple watch (while watch is in background): at intervals 30 sec, 45 sec, 15 sec, 30 sec, etc.

I am worried that since the notifications are so close together, iOS will not send them ON TIME, for whatever reason.

Any ideas on how to do this in Obj C? What kind of trouble should I look out for? Would swift be better?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by ON TIME? what kind of accuracy and precision are you looking for?

Comment: Apple provides a good doc about this here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html.  Language won't make any difference.  You could improve this question by trying, posting what you tried, including timing results that don't meet your requirements.

Comment: By on time, I mean +/- 2 seconds max. I'm just worried that iOS will try to batch close messages together, then send them all at once, for example.

Comment: I've checked the docs and read up on Notification Center, however I can't seem to find much info about how WatchKit handles local notifications.